# Using Facebook Data in yEd

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphics, complexity-theory

How to insert FB data (eg. mutual friends) in yEd to create a graph? 
I saved my data as a mydata.graphml to insert it to yEd. Is there any criterion for the format, deleting empty/unnecessary lines?

Answer (score 0):

I am using yEd with xgml files, so I am not sure how your graphml file looks like. In my case, I used yEd backwards: I first built an example using the graphical interface, then saved it in xgml format to see how yEd structures the data, then constructed a new xgml file by using the minimal amount of lines yEd needs. How to figure out the minimal amount of lines? Isolate the code corresponding to a node, then remove all the unnecessary staff like its x,y position, label positions, etc. This stuff will be automatically interpreted by the yEd GUI anyway, or reformatted through its GUI.

At any rate, it would help if you could post a snippet.